# Find and compare last two non zero values in a range

Tags: excel-formula

Would like to search range A1:G1 and compare the last two non zero values and return the word "Better" if the last value is higher than the second to last or "Worse" if the last value is lower than the second to last.  Some cells may be empty.  Example below.

```
45  6   7   0       4   Worse
```

1       45  65  0       0   Better

Comment: Remember that if the formula provided below works to mark it as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer it is something only you can do.  In fact you should probably go back to your other question and mark @Jeeped answer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(INDEX(A1:G1,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A1:G1)/(A1:G1>0),2))>INDEX(A1:G1,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A1:G1)/(A1:G1>0),1)),"Worse","Better")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The AGGREGATE() function was introduced in excel 2010.

EDIT: Per the comments:

```
=IF(INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,(COLUMN($E23:$CB23)-COLUMN($E:$E)+1)/($E23:$CB23>0),2))>INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,(COLUMN($E23:$CB23)-COLUMN($E:$E)+1)/($E23:$CB23>0),1)),"Worse",IF(INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,(COLUMN($E23:$CB23)-COLUMN($E:$E)+1)/($E23:$CB23>0),2))<INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,(COLUMN($E23:$CB23)-COLUMN($E:$E)+1)/($E23:$CB23>0),1)),"Better","No Change"))
```

Comment: Having some trouble.  I trialed the above formula in a test worksheet with data and it worked as planned.  I then copied the formula to an active worksheet that has data already present, real aligned the ranges which returned #REF!.  To eliminate copy as a problem, I manually entered the formula with the correct ranges and still returned #REF!.   To note, the range being looked in in the active sheet contains formulas that returns data that is calculated from above rows.

Comment: post the formula as you are using it in the comment. @M.Boes

Comment: I believe your problem is that your range does not start on column A anymore.  So you need to make some adjustments.  So for example if the range started in column G I would need to change `COLUMN(A1:G1)` to `COLUMN(G1:O1)-column(G1:G1)+1`  I did not do this in the formula because I started in column A.  This is trying return the column number of the Range referred to in the first criterion in the INDEX Formula.  So in the case here column G would actually be 1.  So we need to make adjustments.

Comment: Formula as used to search Range $E23:$CB23.  =IF(INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E23:$CB23)/($E23:$CB23>0),2))>INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E23:$CB23)/($E23:$CB23>0),1)),"Worse","Better")

Comment: I didn't think of it at the start of the thread but having the formula return "No Change" if the last two non zero where equal would be nice.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @M.Boes see edit.  Please remember to mark as correct, when it works.

Comment: Latest formula does not return the correc resutls.  =IF(INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E23:$CB23)-COLUMN($E23:$E23)+1/($E23:$CB23>0),2))>INDEX($E23:$CB23,,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E23:$CB23)-COLUMN($E2:$E2)+1/($E23:$CB23>0),1)),"Worse","Better")

Comment: I works for me, so without your actual data I cannot test it any further.  Try tearing the formula apart.  Put `=4+AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E23:$CB23)-COLUMN($E23:$E23)+1/($E2‌​3:$CB23>0),2))` in and see if it gives the right column then do the same with the other.  If not try to figure out why.

Comment: Formula provided does work for the question that was asked.  I believe I have a new and different problem.  For some reason the formula does not want to work with the calcuated data contained in the range.  When I re-enter the data manually over the calculated data it works.  I will open a new question.

Comment: I found my problem. The calcuated formula used in the range that the AGGREGATE function searches in is  =IF(E11=0,"0",(+E11-E14)/((E12-E13)/60)) and has text part of the in IFStatement.  When I removed the "0" the AGGREGATE formula worked intended which is the same effect when I manually entered the data.  I would really like to keep the "0" as it allows for a supporting graph to appear correctly.  Is there a way for the AGGREGATE to ignor errors and text in the range?

Comment: Either don't make it text make it a simple `0` instead of `"0"` or you can use `isnumber($E23:$CB23)`  In al the place of `($E23:$CB23>0)`

Comment: Modifed to use isnumber($E23:$CB23) and worked as desired.  Thanks!